# Разница между "какая" и "такая"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли говорить "ты почему какая (красивая, грустная)" вместо "такая"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

1) Правильно: **Ты почему такая красивая** (= какой я тебя вижу)? Также: Ты такая красивая! Ты такая красивая... Употребляется в любых предложениях.

2) К**акая ты красивая!** Употребляется в **восклицательных предложениях**. Какой - вопросительное местоимение, в восклицательных предложениях оно используется для выражения эмоциональной оценки говорящим какого-л. явления, действия, субъекта (удивление, негодование, восхищение).

Можно связать вопрос и восклицание: какая красивая? в какой степени красивая? Нет предела  красоте.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что второй вариант (с восклицанием) требует постановки "какой" в абсолютное начало фразы (максимум - после междометия или частицы). В рассматриваемом примере даже это не выполняется, что вообще снимает всякие сомнения в его, примера, ненормативности.

Comment: Вы ведь это не в абсолютном смысле? Перед "какой(ая,ие)" в восклицательном предложении можно много чего разместить, если начать с "А" или с междометия: "А бриллианты на краях вон того золотого подноса с чёрной икрой какие красивые!"